# Books on Technological Progress and Growth

Tags: macroeconomics, microeconomics, economic-growth, endogenous-growth, directed-technical-change

I've done some google search for good, reader friendly albeit technical, books on technological progress/change and economic growth. However, I've not found what I want. If you are using or have heard about a title on the above topics, do please list them below in your post.

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend [ADVANCED
MACROECONOMICS
Fourth Edition](http://bayanbox.ir/view/5531236431167536065/advanced-macroeconomics.pdf) by David Romer.

Its a textbook for advanced macroeconomics, however it covers the topics in a very precise way. Id recommend reading chapters 1  in order to review the basic Solow model and then chapter 3 to see how the model changes when accounting for human capital and endogenous technological growth.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Daron Acemoglu's comprehensive book "[Introduction to Modern Economic Growth](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/8764.html)" is a very good source of models and analysis related to technological change and growth.

There is a copy of an earlier manuscript that he distributed online [here](http://www.ppge.ufrgs.br/giacomo/arquivos/eco02237/acemoglu-2007.pdf).